# $USER environment variable not changed to root

Tags: centos, environment-variables

The USER env variable is unchanged after gaining root access.

```
[user1@comp]$ echo $USER
user1
```

Logged in the system as 'user1'. Now check the output after gaining root access.

```
[user1@comp]$ su
Password: 

[root@comp]# echo $USER
user1
```

If I were to login as 'root' user, then USER env is set to 'root'. There is no issue there. This behavior was observed in Fedora and CentOS. Why is the env variable not updated?

Comment: what OS are you on? the `$USER` env variable often doesnt get updated when you switch to root, you can try `whoami` or some other alternative like , I have read `who am i` works for some people too (but not for me on Ubuntu)

Comment: @the_velour_fog. Thanks that didn't click my mind

Answer (score 1):

Use `su -` instead, to ensure you inherit the root env.

Comment: Ah. i just needed to do `man su` to understand my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo -E su` command which is set them in `/etc/environment`.